# Generate class on form if generated through shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a wordpress plugin I am currently developing that allows the users to use a shortcode inside of a post, which then generates a form on the page/post.

Now if the user uses the shortcode the generate the form in a post or something, I want to be able to add a specific class, say 'front-end-form', so I can add some styles to style it a certain way on the front end as opposed to the admin dashboard.

I have my shortcode that grabs the form function and prints it, but I'm stuck on the attributes part, or how to add a class through the shortcode. This is the first time I'm getting in to the shortcode API

Thanks for the help guys!

Here is how I add my shortcode

`add_shortcode('wp-upload-form', 'uploader_form');`

This is what I have at the start of my function (I don't believe this to be right)

`extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'front-end-uploader-form'
    ), $atts ) );`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but if your short code is like `[wp-upload-form class="fancyform"]` then this form should output with default of 'defaultClass' unless you specify the class.

```
function uploader_form($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array("class" => 'defaultClass'), $atts));
$html = '<div class="' . $class . '"><form></form></div>';
return ($html);
}
```

If this doesn't work maybe post both of your entire functions here.